# Issue on clearing user input

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to optimize an existing ASP.NET web application I am having some issue on understanding what is handling the event on one of page buttons. In `Default.aspx` I have a Control which looks like:

```
<asp:Button ID="ClearBtn" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="thin" 
  runat="server" Text="Clear"  onclick="ClearFilterButton_Click" />
```

and in `Default.aspx.cs` I have a method which looks like:

```
protected void ClearFilterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list = null;
    FilterDateFrom.Text = "";
    FilterDateTo.Text = "";
    FrontFilteredItems.Update();
    AdvSearchPanel.Update();
    AssetClassUpdatePanel.Update();

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(SearchCriteriaUpdatePanel, SearchCriteriaUpdatePanel.GetType(),
         Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ReceiveFilterData('[]'); clearSearchPanelFields(); ", true);
}
```

Technically what this method s suppose to do is clearing user input but even when I totally comment the entire method definition like

```
protected void ClearFilterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //list = null;
    //FilterDateFrom.Text = "";
    //FilterDateTo.Text = "";
    //FrontFilteredItems.Update();
    //AdvSearchPanel.Update();
    //AssetClassUpdatePanel.Update();
    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(SearchCriteriaUpdatePanel, SearchCriteriaUpdatePanel.GetType(),
    //     Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ReceiveFilterData('[]'); clearSearchPanelFields(); ", true);
}
```

but there is still something which handling the clear button event as I get "validation Warning Message!. What else can be handled in this method action?

Comment: Do a Response.Redirect back to same page?

Answer (score 1):

Validation errors like that usually come from ASP.Net validator controls.

There is a list of built-in validator controls here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x(v=vs.100).aspx

Look for something like this in the page's markup (HTML):

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        Display="Static"
        ErrorMessage="*"
        runat="server"/>
```